# Compiler defined symbol not found from code

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor, avr, mplab

I'm using AVR GCC compiler v5.4.0 under MPLAB X IDE v5.45.
I defined a symbol for the compiler in the `avr-as-pre` section. It adds the following to the invoked command:

```
-DF_CPU=32000000UL
```

Inside the code I have some checks like this:

```
#ifndef F_CPU
    // do something
```

and it actually *does* something. It looks like if it doesn't find the symbol.
Am I wrong about how to define a symbol for the whole project in this way?

### UPDATE

The IDE calls this stuff "defined symbols":

[image]

but it stores them as "preprocessor macros" actually:

```
  <AVR-AS-PRE>
    <property key="announce-version" value="false"/>
    <property key="include-paths" value=""/>
    <property key="preprocessor-macros" value="F_CPU=32000000UL"/>
    <property key="preprocessor-macros-undefined" value=""/>
    <property key="suppress-warnings" value="false"/>
  </AVR-AS-PRE>
```

Unfortunately it seems it does not pass them to the compiler:

```
$ grep -nrw . -e F_CPU
./nbproject/configurations.xml:117:        <property key="preprocessor-macros" value="F_CPU=32000000UL"/>
```

Comment: That's the correct syntax, and it works fine in a test: https://godbolt.org/z/dxoxMa3rc.  So probably the `-D` option is not actually making it to the compiler; I'm not familiar with this IDE so I'm not sure if where you've added this option is the right place.  One note is that what you're defining is not a *symbol* (which is a name resolved to an address at link time) but rather a *macro* (which is only used in preprocessing); any chance that confusion is related?

Comment: @NateEldredge, I guess you're right. I've update the question.

Comment: Using the "avr-as-pre" section is suspect unless you actually have assembly-language files in your project.  "avr-as" is the name of the GNU assembler for AVR.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, that makes sense. I was betrayed by the `pre` suffix - I guessed it stands for `preprocessor` but I didn't think about the `as` part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the compiler symbols under `avr-gcc > Preprocessing and messages > Defined symbols` section:

[image]